# HTML insertBefore and layout/reflow management

Tags: performance, dom, html-rendering

I have a list which I want to update in response to event whose payload contains a new list item. I want to prepend the new list item to the list.

I am using the following logic to prepend the new 'msg' received from the event to the list.

```
<html>

<script>

    function addItem() {
        setInterval(() => {

            var ul = document.getElementById('mylist');
            var newItem = document.createElement('li')
            newItem.innerHTML = 'hello0.0'
            ul.insertBefore(newItem, ul.childNodes[0]);
        }, 1000);
    }

</script>


<body>
   <button onclick='addItem()'> </button>
    <ul id='mylist'>
        <li id="insertPoint">  hello1 </li>
        <li>  hello2 </li>
    </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Now when I profile this on chrome, everytime the event happens there is a reflow which is expected. Chrome tells me that about 7 nodes need layout. This number is constant even when the list has hundreds of items.

Now my questions are

i) What are these 7 nodes that need layout ?

ii) The paint seems to done on the whole document as the list is directly attached to the body. So if the list has 1000 items, even though the layout happens for only 7 nodes, all the items still need to be repainted. Are there any smarter tactics to avoid this ?

Comment: Nodes can be elements, text, comments, whitespace, etc... Kinda impossible to know unless you provide a layout of your HTML

Comment: I have updated the snippet with  minimum code to reproduce my case. Upon profiling in chrome, I see that about 7 nodes need layout every time the timer fires

Comment: OK, now remove the whitespaces that are around the text: "hello1" and "hello2". See if you still get 7 nodes.

Comment: yes its still 7. If there are 1000 items in the list, dont all these item nodes need to be layout-ed again ? All of them move by an index of 1, so their position changes and I imagine the layout needs to run on all of them. Why is it a constant ?

Comment: Just noticed...why are you using `setInterval()`? A loop with a limit is not only practical, but also more efficient and of course faster. It looks as if you had no plan of ever stopping? I think you are looking at the car's speedometer expecting 100MPH but you got your foot on the brake.

Answer (score 2):

### Update

After having been provided with the HTML, I setup a [**test case**](https://jsperf.com/so47252206) that comprises of the following methods:

- [**.prepend()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/prepend)
- [**.before()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/before)
- [**.insertBefore()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore)
- [**insertAdjacentElement()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentElement)
- [**insertAdjacentHTML()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)

Overall speed is the bottom line, repaints is just one part of a bigger world that is the DOM. On Chrome both `insertAdjacentElement/HTML` were considerably faster than `insertBefore()` (by @10%), while in Firefox only marginally (by .55%).

---

> i) What are these 7 nodes that need layout ?

Nodes can be elements, text, comments, whitespace, etc. so it depends on the context. It sounds trivial it being a constant of 7.

> ii) The paint seems to done on the whole document as the list is directly attached to the body. So if the list has 1000 items, even though the layout happens for only 7 nodes, all the items still need to be repainted. Are there any smarter tactics to avoid this ?

The only way to avoid a full repaint of the page is AJAX AFAIK.

Try `insertAdjacentHTML()` although its name is a mouthful, it's a very fast and flexible method. Here's the signature:

*element*.**insertAdjacentHTML(** *"position"*, *string*);

- **element:** any element capable of holding content (i.e. has an end tag `</*>`)
- **"position":** There four positions which are relative to the **element**:

  1. **"beforebegin":** The element to be inserted (i.e. the second parameter: *string*), would be placed in front of *element*. eq. `insertBefore()`

     - ex. **`<li>string</li>`** `<ul>element</ul>`
  2. **"afterbegin":** *string* would be placed within *element* in front of all of the children. eq. `parentNode.prepend()`

     - ex. `<ul>` **`<li>string</li>`** , `<li>item</li>`, `<li>item</li>` `</ul>`
  3. **"beforeend":** *string* is inserted inside *element* as the last child. eq. `appendChild()`

     - ex. `<ul>` `<li>item</li>`, `<li>item</li>`, **`<li>string</li>`** `</ul>`
  4. **"afterend":** *string* is placed after *element*. eq. doesn't exist and besides just using `insertAdjacentHTML()` the other alternative is too confusing I'm not going to bother to include it.

     - ex.  `<ul>` `<li>item</li>`, `<li>item</li>` `</ul>` **`<li>string</li>`**
  5. **string:** This is a string that represents one or more elements to be rendered into HTML. eq. `innerHTML`

### Demo

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
const li = `<li class='item'>Item</li>`;
const ul = document.querySelector('.ul');

btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  ul.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', li);
}, false);
```

```html
<button class='btn'>ADD</button>
<ul class='ul'></ul>
```

Comment: Hows it different to insertBefore in terms of performance p.o.v ? Also, I am not sure what ajax has got to do here ?

Comment: I wrote that before you updated your question with HTML, so I couldn't include a test comparing both of them. AJAX can insert HTML (i.e. manipulate DOM) without causing a full page refresh and/or repaint.

Comment: Can confirm that ajax has nothing to do with this. Ajax is only just a model for sending and receiving data with JavaScript, so that no hard refreshes are needed for anything from navigation to form submissions. The model itself has *nothing* to do with the reflows/repaints that happen when you manipulate the DOM...